# Argument type {query: () => "products"} is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have this error and its only in WebStorm. In VS code it's OK.

Do I need to change some configurations or I did a mistake somewhere?

> Argument type `{query: () => "products"}` is not assignable to parameter type `OmitFromUnion<QueryDefinition<number, BaseQuery, TagTypes, IProduct[], ReducerPath>, "type">`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue - created more deep question

[WebStorm warning: Argument type is not assignable to parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788617/webstorm-warning-argument-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type)

I've found one way to fix it - (in your case) destructure `query` from `build`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).